# TAG= 'Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 29,Token in error = FROM ' ... insert data from one column to another column of other table

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, razor, database-schema

Well... I have two tables named : "chefs" and "cust_Data".

I want to :

1. Put comments from cust_Data that are being posted into the comment column in chefs table.
2. By being posted means-> M giving a comment section so that customers will put their comments in "comment" column in "cust_Data" and as soon as those comments are in cust_Data...
3. Put those comment in "comments" column in "chefs" table.

## RAZOR CODE:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("vendors");
    var selectCommand = "SELECT dish FROM chefs WHERE ID= @0";      
    var chefID = Request.QueryString["chefid"];  
    var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, chefID);
    var dishName=Request.QueryString["dish"];      
    var chefName=Request.QueryString["chefName"];           

    var comments=Request["SELECT comments from chefs"];   //IMPORTANT
    var ID=Request["SELECT ID from chefs"];               //IMPORTANT

    var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, rowsPerPage: 10);

    Validation.RequireField("cust_fname", "You must enter your firstname");
    Validation.RequireField("cust_lname", "You must enter your surname");
    Validation.RequireField("cust_email", "You haven't entered a valid Email_ID");
    Validation.RequireField("rating", "Rating is required");
    Validation.RequireField("comment", "Please provide your Comment about Respective Homeschef");

    var cust_fname = "";
    var cust_lname= "";
    var cust_email= "";
    var rating= "";
    var comment= "";      //IMPORTANT

     if(IsPost && Validation.IsValid() && chefID.AsInt()!=0){
       cust_fname = Request.Form["cust_fname"];
       cust_lname = Request.Form["cust_lname"];
       cust_email = Request.Form["cust_email"];
       rating = Request.Form["rating"];   
       comment = Request.Form["comment"];    // IMPORTANT->TAKING COMMENT FROM USER

       var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO cust_Data (cust_fname, cust_lname, cust_email, dish, chef_ID, rating, comment) Values(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)";
       db.Execute(insertCommand,cust_fname,cust_lname, cust_email, dishName, chefID, rating, comment);   // EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY IN cust_Data
       var insert= "INSERT INTO chefs(comments) FROM cust_Data(comment) WHERE chefs(ID)=cust_Data(chef_ID) Values(@0,@1,@2,@3)"; //IMPORTANT
       db.Execute(insert,comments,comment,ID,chefID);    // IMPORTANT -> ERROR OCCURED ?????????

    }

}
```

Exception Details: `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 29,Token in error = FROM ]`

I inserted IMPORTANT TAG(to save your time for important things) from where i took the parameters I needed to parse.
Again, Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: I'm proud of you for your achievements! By the way, did you mean to ask us a question?

Comment: Your last insert into syntax is messed up. Read [w3schools.com > insert into select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) for proper syntax. Why are you fetching ID, Comments from 2 separate requests from DB?

Comment: thanks for the reply @Spidey...

There is still token line error=79.     
var insert= "INSERT INTO chefs(comments) SELECT cust_Data(comment) WHERE chefs(ID)=cust_Data(chef_ID) Values(@0,@1,@2,@3)";

Answer (score 0):

> Though this is not a complete answer, writing this as a answer as the content for explanation is too long.

---

Even though you've updated the `insert into` command, the select statement is still wrong. You are trying to write the select statement using the syntax of insert statement i.e. `table_name(column_name)` but it should be

```
SELECT column_name from table_name WHERE table_name.column_name=''
```

`Insert into` statement works by taking complete SQL `select` statement prefixed by `Insert Into` clause. So, your code should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO chefs(comments) SELECT comments from cust_Data WHERE chefs.ID=cust_Data.chef_ID
```

But this won't work as you've not joined the table `chefs` and `cust_data`. So you will have to join both the tables and get the correct records, then use the insert into command to insert the records into the `chefs` table.

---

Looking more into your program, it looks like you want to update the existing records from the chefs table, or insert is the correct one? Your `chefs` table has other columns i.e. `ID`,`dish` which have been ignored in the insert statement. I doubt that this insert statement would run properly without these columns.

Also, why are you querying comments and ID values separately. And the rows are also not filtered, so it will fetch all the records from the database.

```
var comments=Request["SELECT comments from chefs"];   //IMPORTANT
var ID=Request["SELECT ID from chefs"];               //IMPORTANT
```

The database structure and your agenda that you are trying to achieve looks weird to me. I.e. Customer enters the data in `cust_data.comments` and you want to move/copy these comments to `chefs.comment` and as soon as the data comes in `cust_data` table. Why not directly insert into the chefs table instead of this 2 step approach.

*Have you thought about the whole process from start to finish? Have you drawn it on paper or screen using UML diagram/process flow?*

---

*It looks like you do not have enough experience on the database side. My suggestion would be that you first try these statements directly on the database tool SSMS, get it confirmed that it's working and then apply it in your program. You can use hard coded values for testing and then substitute with parameters when applying it into the program.*

*Also it would help you if you can learn `Stored Procedures` and use that in your program. This will reduce such complications from program side and also reduce the database calls*